# Connectors similar to Lego "wire and plate" pieces

Tags: connector

In 2006, Lego discontinued their "wire and plate" pieces. Here is a picture:
[image]

For a project, we need this kind of "top down" flat connector - the thinner the better. I'm not asking for a specific product recommendation, but I am trying to understand what I should be searching for. How is this kind of connector best described?

Comment: Won't breadboard suffice?

Comment: Or just google "female header".

Comment: they discontinued that one but introduced a new one : https://shop.lego.com/en-CA/LEGO-Power-Functions-Extension-Wire-20-8871

Comment: use descriptive words to limit your question, for example: "must be snap-on,snap-off, very low profile, multi-pole connector" "Pin headers are not suitable because" "single wire Snap Fasteners have too large a footprint"

Comment: how about the snap connectors used on 9V batteries? theyre about as high as a lego plate

Comment: also look at mezzanine boart-to-board connectors, possibly used with flex PCB instead of wire.

Answer (score 3):

These 2 connectors came to my mind:

Female header for smaller current needs

[image: header]

Banana plug for larger current needs

[image: banana plug]